# jQuery function requires two clicks

Tags: jquery, click

I need to adjust the CSS of one element when a tab is clicked if a particular class ('current') is present. The class 'current' is added when the tab is clicked. The code I have works, but it takes two clicks - I think because on the first click, the class is added and then on the second, jQuery detects it. Here's the jquery code:

```
    $('ul.tabs a').click(function() {
     if($('a#tab5').hasClass('current')) {
        $('#rightCorner').css("top","1px");
     } else {
        $('#rightCorner').css("top","7px");
     };
})
```

Is there a way to get it to work with one click?

Thanks - Joe

Comment: Why does clicking on the tab add a class? I think I will need to see all of the relevant code before I can answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you combine the code that adds the `current` class and this click handler that monitors tab5? This allows you to add the class and then perform the check. The order of operations is going wrong in your case.

```
$('ul.tabs a').click(function() {     
     $('ul.tabs a').removeClass('current');
     $(this).addClass('current');
     if (this.id == 'tab5') {
          $('#rightCorner').css("top","1px");
     }
     else {
          $('#rightCorner').css("top","7px");
     }
})
```

Update:

Probably easier to just handle tab 5 using CSS instead of the if statement.

```
ul.tabs a#tab5 { top: 7px; }
ul.tabs a#tab5.current { top 1px; }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks tons.

Comment: @user1286623 - If this solution works for you then please tick the checkmark next to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Just finally figured that out. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

In the `else` branch you might need to add

```
$('a#tab5').addClass('current');
```